# Having trouble finding source for NumericObservable in Knockout (KO)

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I am looking at some source code and I see examples that refer to a KnockoutJS numeric observable function:

```
var x = ko.numericObservable(0);
```

However, when I google around, I can't find any documentation on such a function. In fact, with KO 2.2.0 loaded, my attempt to use the above code results in an "undefined is not a function" error.

Strangely, I see numericObservable off the ko object when I get an intellisense popup within Visual Studio 2013--so I don't know enough about intellisense to know whether it is wrong or whether there is some other problem.

I'd be grateful for some assistance here.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never heard about numericObservable, if you are new with ko you should have a look at observable or computed.

What do you want to do ?

Comment: I'm guessing the project you are looking at has added the `ko.numericObservable`, since it is not part of KnockoutJS proper. It is possible that the `numericObservable` is based on the `numericObservable` used as an example at http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html.

Comment: The example on this page uses ko.numericObservable():
http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Using_Wijmo_with_Knockout

Comment: I think they were trying to set the initial value for males and females to an integer while simultaneously make them observable values.

Comment: @Jazimov in your linked example the `ko.numericObservable` is part of the `knockout.wijmo.js` file (http://cdn.wijmo.com/external/knockout.wijmo.js)

Comment: @nemesv: That's brilliant of you to find that! I never would have expected or suspected that Wijmo made a custom knockout function. No wonder there is no citation on Google. (Isn't that a bad idea for Wijmo folks to make??? What happens when new KO versions appear???) If you make your reply an answer I can accept that answer. Thanks!

Comment: @nemesv: I will write to Wijmo to find out whether what their "best practice" is. I imagine some people are going to want to use the latest KO version AND the one Wijmo has tested/enhanced to work with Wijmo. It seems rather messy to me and Wijmo probably should have been more clear about what role their KO version plays in all of this.

Comment: I'd think that making `numeric` an extender would likely be the "best practice" approach. There is even an example of making a `numeric` extender in [the knockout documentation on extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).

Answer (score 0):

`ko.numericObservable` is part of Wijmo-Knockout library. A Knokout integration for [Wijmo UI](http://wijmo.com/).

More information [here](http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Using_Wijmo_with_Knockout)